# Precompiling Handlebar templates with Backbone Layoutmanager for Jasmine tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, templates, backbone.js, jasmine

**Folks**,

Our project is rapidly growing in size and I wanted to be a good JS-citizen and get testing implemented before it is too late. We're creating our front-end using Backbone with Backbone Layoutmanager and Handlebars templates among other things, and I've read [some](http://open.bekk.no/integration-testing-backbone-js/) [excellent](http://kilon.org/blog/2012/08/testing-backbone-requirejs-applications-with-jasmine/) blog posts on how  to test Backbone-driven apps using [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) with Jasmine-Jquery and [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/), so I decided to go for that.

However, our setup is a little atypical, as we're using RequireJS modules, augmenting Backbone with Layoutmanager, and precompiling Handlebars templates. We're precompiling the templates asynchronously [as is suggested](https://github.com/tbranyen/boilerplate-handlebars-layoutmanager/blob/master/app/app.js) by the creators of these libraries, and I spent the better part of a long day banging my head before I realized that any type of async jQuery/Ajax call won't work if you're running the app using Jasmine.
Trying to make the `$.ajax(...)` call synchronous with `async: false` didn't do it, and digging into the Layoutmanager JS source I saw that it all is meant to happen async.

So anyways this is how I ended up making the precompilation work in the end:

```
Backbone.LayoutManager.configure({
    manage: false,

    prefix: "app/templates/",

    fetch: function(path) {
        var done;
        var that = this;

        // Concatenate the file extension.
        path = path + ".html";

        runs(function() {
            if (!JST[path]) {
                done = that.async()

                return $.ajax({ url: app.root + path, async: false }).then(
                    //Successhandler
                    function(contents) {
                        JST[path] = Handlebars.compile(contents);
                        JST[path].__compiled__ = true;
                        done(JST[path]);
                    },
                    //Errorhandler
                    function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        //Feil ved lasting av template
                        //TODO logg feil på en eller annen måte
                    }
                );
            }
            // If the template hasn't been compiled yet, then compile.
            if (!JST[path].__compiled__) {
                JST[path] = Handlebars.compile(JST[path]);
                JST[path].__compiled__ = true;
            }
        });

        waitsFor(function() {
            return done;
        }, "loading template", 500);
        return JST[path];
    },

    // Override render to use Handlebars
    render: function(template, context) {
        return template(context);
    }

});
```

The solution was to wrap the async logic in `runs` and `waitFor` it.

**Now for the question**:
I don't think this is an optimal solution, because it forces me to duplicate app.js just to wrap the async call. Are there any better approaches to this problem?

If there aren't then fair enough, hopefully someone else learned from this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a solution that avoids duplicating app.js unfortunately. But that file rarely changes, so it isn't really an issue.
I have however made some improvements to the async handling above, to make it more robust:

```
    waitsFor(function() {
        return JST[path] && JST[path].__compiled__;
    }, "loading template", 1000);
    return JST[path];
```

The line `done(JST[path]);` can then be removed.

The tests run more stable now, previously they would sometimes fail due to templates not loading correctly.

Accepting this as an answer.

Comment: Had a similar issue recently, not sure if you saw: https://github.com/tbranyen/boilerplate-handlebars-layoutmanager/blob/master/app/app.js I ended up using a variation of this but have all my templates precompiled as part of the dev process so they are all in one file (compiled-templates.js) and loaded via require as a dependency. You do need to set __compiled__ = true prior to returning the val. You could keep the individual file ajax compilation for fail-safe if any files didn't get added to the pre-compiled bundle for any reason.